# Error in implementing reinforcement learning model using quantum circuit

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have done most of the part plz see the below code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class HadamardLayer(layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

  def build(self, input_shape):
    super().build(input_shape)

  def call(self, inputs):
    hadamard_gate = tf.constant([[1/np.sqrt(2), 1/np.sqrt(2)],
                                 [1/np.sqrt(2), -1/np.sqrt(2)]])
    return tf.linalg.matmul(hadamard_gate, inputs)

class QuantumExplorationCircuit(keras.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.qubits = layers.Input(shape=(1,))  # Assuming 1 qubit for exploration
    self.h = HadamardLayer()  # Use custom Hadamard layer

  def call(self, inputs):
    super().call(inputs)
    exploration_prob = self.h(inputs)
    return exploration_prob

def run_episode_tensorflow(sess, env, action_prob, exploration_circuit):
  obs = env.reset()
  done = False

  state_list = []
  action_list = []
  r_list = []
  while not done:
    cur_action_prob = sess.run(action_prob, feed_dict={observation_placeholder: obs.reshape(1, 4)})


#error is here TypeError: Can not convert a NoneType into a Tensor or Operation.
    exploration_probs = sess.run(exploration_circuit, feed_dict={exploration_placeholder: np.zeros((1, 1))})

    combined_prob = (1 - epsilon) * cur_action_prob[0] + epsilon * exploration_probs[0]
    action = np.random.choice([0, 1], p=combined_prob)

    state_list.append(obs)
    action_list.append(action)
    obs, r, done, info = env.step(action)
    r_list.append(r)
  return state_list, action_list, r_list

epsilon = tf.constant(0.05, dtype=tf.float32)
observation_placeholder = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, 4))
action_placeholder = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=())
v = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=())

model_params = tf.Variable(tf.compat.v1.random_uniform(shape=(4, 2), minval=0, maxval=1.0, dtype=tf.float32))
preds = tf.matmul(observation_placeholder, model_params)
action_prob = tf.nn.softmax(preds)

exploration_placeholder = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, 1))
exploration_circuit = QuantumExplorationCircuit()

action_grad = tf.gradients(tf.compat.v1.log(action_prob[:, action_placeholder]), model_params)
update_step = model_params.assign(model_params + epsilon * tf.squeeze(action_grad) * v)

tries_list = []

for episode in range(100):
  num_tries = 0
  cur_r = 0

  with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())

    while cur_r < 200:
      state_list, action_list, r_list = run_episode_tensorflow(sess, env, action_prob, exploration_circuit)
      cur_r = sum(r_list)
      num_tries += 1
      for idx, (state, action) in enumerate(zip(state_list, action_list)):
        _ = sess.run(update_step, feed_dict={observation_placeholder: state.reshape(1, 4), action_placeholder: action, v:sum(r_list[idx:])})

    tries_list.append(num_tries)

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(tries_list, bins=max(tries_list), align='left')
plt.xlabel('Number of episodes before solving environment')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.title('Results of Monte Carlo Policy Gradient with Quantum Exploration')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

error is

TypeError: Can not convert a NoneType into a Tensor or Operation.

for rest of the file
here is an editable link of my google colab file do see if you can make it work

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RYKXvMtDZqRD2T2b39N04VjNmolLC-QS#scrollTo=g1s1EnHJTLUy